# autozoom canvas to fit bitmap

Tags: android, canvas

In my custom views `OnDraw` method I draw a `Bitmap` to the center of the `Canvas` with

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Rect r = canvas.getClipBounds();
    displayWidth = r.right;
    displayHeight = r.bottom;
    camera.applyToCanvas(canvas);
    float zW = (float)bitmapWidth / (float)displayWidth;
    float zH = (float)bitmapHeight / (float)displayHeight;
    float z = 0.0f;
    if (zW>1 || zH>1) {
        z = Math.max(zW, zH); 
    }
    canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (displayWidth/2.0f - (bitmapWidth)/2.0f), (displayHeight/2.0f - bitmapHeight/2.0f), paint);
    if (z>0) {
        camera.translate(z, -z, z);
    }
}
```

If the `Bitmap` is larger in height or width is larger then `Canvas` size (`displayWidth, displayHeight`), how can I use the `Camera` class to autozoom to fit the `Bitmap` and center it to the `Canvas`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a Matrix instance and initialize it using

`public boolean setRectToRect (RectF src, RectF dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit stf)`

You need to do this only once and keep the matrix in memory. Note that `Matrix.ScaleToFit` define the `CENTER` value.

Later when you draw the bitmap use this version of the drawBitmap:

`public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)`